# aws eb InvalidParameterValueError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I am not familiar with aws, and one of my friends handed me over a project and now I am trying to deploy it to existing eb instance, and I tried eb init but keep getting this error. Please help me.

```
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Platform 'arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-northeast-2::platform/Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.14.2' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

The EB platform you are trying to use was [valid](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-docker.html) only between February 28, 2020 and March 26, 2020.

The [current version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.docker) for Amazon Linux 1 is `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.15.2 running Docker 19.03.6-ce`.

Thus, you have to upgrade your settings to use the current version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried, and I got another problem. Once I got to the settings of the instance, I found out that the button to change the platform is disabled. This means that I have to create another instance and migrate all the settings and then deploy my application, right?